# Parser error inside razor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013

[image]I am trying to use Captcha inside my project but get a parser error with the following code...struggling to eliminate it

```
@{MvcCaptcha registrationCaptcha = CaptchaHelper.GetRegistrationCaptcha(); }
@if (!registrationCaptcha.IsSolved)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
            @Html.Captcha(registrationCaptcha)
        </div>
        @Html.Label("Retype the code", new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label", @for = "CaptchaCode" })
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.TextBox("CaptchaCode", null, new { @class = "form-control captchaVal" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

What would the cause be of the parser error?

Comment: Please post the exception message

Comment: I did update it, changing '@if' to 'if' still gives an error

Comment: It looks like you are already in a razor code block. Try just dropping the `@` - just `if (!registrationCaptcha.IsSolved)`{ ...`

Comment: taking away the @ gives the following message Parser Error Message: Unexpected "{" after "@" character. Once inside the body of a code block (@if {}, @{}, etc.) you do not need to use "@{" to switch to code.

Answer (score 0):

managed to rectify it

```
            MvcCaptcha registrationCaptcha = CaptchaHelper.GetRegistrationCaptcha();  

            if (!registrationCaptcha.IsSolved)
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
                        @Html.Captcha(registrationCaptcha)
                    </div>

                    @Html.Label("Retype the code",
              new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label", @for = "CaptchaCode" })

                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.TextBox("CaptchaCode", null,
                  new { @class = "form-control captchaVal" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
```